# redirect to controller instead of view when validation failed in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel

in my controller :

```
public function getData(\App\Http\Requests\NewNameRequest $request)
{       
    return 'Your name is : '.$request->input('myName');
}
```

in my NewNameRequest.php class

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class NewNameRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'myName'=>'required|min:3|max:10'
        ];
    }
}
```

---

what i want is ...

if (NewNameRequest is Failed)
{
 do this...
}
else
{
proceed ahead in controller
}

thanks in time ahead

Comment: Make yourself clear about what you mean when you say: redirect to controller instead of view. Do you want to call another method inside your controller? Do you want to show another view? Do you want to redirect to a different URL that calls a different controller?

Comment: if validation failed then i want to get all validation error messages in an array reside in SuperController and return back with validation error messages to Wrapercontroller.

Comment: What is the reason you want it to go to a different controller?

Comment: beacause i have one child Controller from where i called to parent controller, and all the validation error messages i want to send to that child controller.